# Issue with sort_value pandas function, ask for "by", but when given, says unexpected argument

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to sort my data frame after transposing it.
Transpose went good.
When trying to sort values, it says

> sort_values() missing 1 required positional argument: 'by'

When I mention the by argument, it says

> sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'by'

This is the dataframe I trying to apply sort_values

```
top_dict = {}
for c in data.columns:
  top = data[c].sort_values(axis=0, ascending=False, inplace=False, kind='quicksort', na_position='last').head(30)
  top_dict[c]= list(zip(top.index, top.values))
```

The weird thing is sort_value works just fine with by command when doing without for loop. When running in loop, this happens

This is the weirdest I have seen. Anyone can help me understand this and point me towards to solution

Comment: Where do you use the argument? As an aside, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: try this `top = data.sort_value(by=[c], ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you're receiving an error because your selected df has become a series? The following should solve that issue.

```
top = data[[c]].sort_values(
    by=c,
    axis=0,
    ascending=False,
    inplace=False,
    kind='quicksort',
    na_position='last'
    ).head(30)
```

Comment: Still getting the same error message 'Unexpected argument'

Comment: Updated my answer @srujanreddyj

Comment: This solves it, but one problem arises when there are some columns with the same name but different data in it.

Comment: That'll be a reference error on the column creation. You may choose to add to your operations (either in the loop or before ir) `my cols = list(df.columns); if my_cols.count(col )>1: do something`

Answer (score 2):

I see you're sorting a column only to take the first 30 values (aka the 30 largest values). Might I recommend `Series.nlargest` to do the same thing, but in a slightly more performant way?

```
top_dict = {}
for c in data.columns:
    top = data[c].nlargest(30)
    top_dict[c]= list(zip(top.index, top.values))
```

Comment: When try this, I get a TypeError: nlargest() missing 1 required positional argument: 'columns'.

So, I tried giving the top = data[c].nlargest(30, c, keep='all'), I get nlargest() got multiple values for argument 'keep'

Comment: Seems that `data[c]` is returning a `DataFrame` instead of a `Series` can you share the output of `print(c)` and `print(data[c])`

Comment: output of print(c) is the column names.

output of print(data[c]) is 

Name: pub.1037916648, Length: 6502, dtype: int64
abilities    0
ability      0
abiotic      0
ablating     0
able         0
            ..
μm           0
μmolkg       0
σy           0
ϕsurf        0
аt           0
Name: pub.1092903466, Length: 6502, dtype: int64

Comment: ah, I think it seems that 2 or more of your columns share the same name in your dataframe! Can you verify that all of the columns in your dataframe have unique names? you can do this with `len(data.columns) == data.columns.nunique()`. You'll need to ensure that no columns share the same name in order for any of the answers on this question to work.

Comment: yes, you are right. Thank you for pointing that out. I removed the duplicate column, and it works. Thank you for introducing me to this new concept